# WPF Как привязать стиль из Windows10?

Tags: c#, wpf

Только вчера сел изучать WPF, так что прошу не кидаться "камнями в мой огород".

Набросал приложение со стандартными стилями. Работал под Win10 и всё получилось красиво, а потом продолжил под Win7 и ужаснулся от того, что изменились стили и всё стало как в Win7!

Пожалуйста, подскажите как можно сохранить стили элементов Win10?
В основном TextBox-ы, ComboBox-ы и CheckBox-ы важны. Можно хотя бы их как-то "вшить" в моё приложение?

Comment: Как привязать стили из 10 не знаю, но знаю что в WPF можно перекрасить анимировать и прочие практически все. Создайте свой стиль максимально похожий на стиль 10, опишите его в ресурсах для текст бокса кнопок и прочего, и в итоге у вас будет выглядеть приложение так как вы его опишите.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar, звучит здорово и грандиозно. А значит кто-то это уже сделал до меня. К тому же описывать всё это... очень много работы, полагаю и к тому же не умею. Ещё можно предположить, что стили хранятся где-то в винде рас уж они меняются от смены ОС. Может можно как-то открыть "исходные" XAMl-ы и добавить нужное к себе в ресурсы?

Comment: На счет этого не знаю. Я такой задачи для себя не когда не ставил.

Comment: [Ищите](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) [наборы](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) [стилей](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) и выбирайте, какой вам подойдет, или пишите свои стили.